# XAML namespaces: winfx vs netfx

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

When looking at the documentation for WPF (e.g. [for `Selector.SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx)), I noticed that there are two XML naspaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation and http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation.

What's the difference between the two, if any? Why are there two different namespaces that seem to point to the same group of .Net namespaces (do they really?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(guessing the answer)

the first version of WPF was called WinFX and was probably a separated project in MS organisation.

When WinFX joined the .Net Framework, MS has probably wished to keep the namespaces defines earlier for compatibility with existing work.
Later, new classes have been added, and MS decided to use a properly named namespace (NetFX is .Net Framework).